# Python throwing error on loading modified json

Tags: python, json, linux, python-2.7

I have a linux machine where the data is stored. We can get that data in json format by some command.
When I load that json file using `python`:

```
    f = open(filename)
    json.load(f)
```

It just works fine as expected.

But when I open that file in Notepad Text Editor and modify value of some variable (say from java_v5 to java_v6), and do same operations mentioned above, suprizingly I get

```
      File "D:\userdata\aagoyal\Desktop\TPD\Import_11_3\json_to_adv.py", line 26, in __init__
        self.dump = json.load(self.f)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
        **kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
        raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`
```

I am not getting why its happening! Its strange that just by modifying a single character in some variable's value (i.e. modifying value of a key of dictionary), I am getting this error.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Is it still JSON? You can check it in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Most likely your editor changed something more that you expected. What that is cannot be determined without seeing the JSON you have now.

Comment: I checked it there. Its valid JSON.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file after modifying? Which editor are you using to modify? Perhaps it's changing the encoding of the text which is causing this issue.

Comment: @Gauranga: did you check with the data that *Python reads*? `print f.read()`, then paste that into jsonlint.

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom As mentioned, I am using Notepad to modify it.

Comment: @Gauranga: but Notepad is not a Linux editor. If you are modifying the file on Windows, how is the file shared?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Modifying on windows and copying back to linux using WinScp. This is one of the test case that I have for testing my script.

Comment: @Gauranga: and have you verified along every step of that path that the only thing changed is the one character? Did you keep a copy of the file? Did you use `diff` to see if anything changed?

Comment: @Gauranga what if  you do `dos2unix` to your file before using it? It will remove DOS characters and will be ready for Unix.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As per your very first comment, I used some different text editor and everything is working fine now. So, something more than what I expected was getting changed. That something should be the json encoding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `Martijn Pieters` and  `Mark Winterbottom`'s comments above, not every editor should be used to modify the JSON data as this may change the encoding of the JSON data. Some text editors (like Notepad) may not support such encodings.
Json uses `UTF-8` encoding while `Notepad` does not. So, an encoding compatible editor only should be used. 
Because its not just about the `JSON string`'s validity, its about `encoding` also.